# How to find the local gem dpendency

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I see a gem package, I want to know which gem packages in my local are using it. Is there any ways to do that?

For example, if I see

```
  gem list minitar

  *** LOCAL GEMS ***

   minitar (0.5.4)
```

I want to know which gem packages in local are using it. thanks. Is there any tool can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i"ve found

```
  "gem dependency -R minitar"
```

can solve my question